# Make Firestore only return users with customer_id that is less than 1000

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

How do I extract the users in my db that has a customer_id with less than 8 digits?

I tried to do this:

`iter := client.Collection("users").Where("customer_id", "<", "10000").Documents(ctx)`

But that doesn't return anything, even though I know I have users that looks like this:

```
 map[customer_id:111]
 map[customer_id:123]
```

If I however do

```
iter := client.Collection("users").Where("customer_id", "==", "111").Documents(ctx)
```

.. it will find that document,

EDIT: I just noticed that customer_id is stored as a string.

Comment: I don't think you can check length, you might have to store the length as a separate field

Comment: If customer_id is stored as an integer, then use an integer value in the condition: `Where("customer_id", "<", 10000)`

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Not a firestore user, but I found some info from https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries.

```golang
countryQuery := cities.Where("state", "==", "CA")
popQuery := cities.Where("population", "<", 1000000)
cityQuery := cities.Where("name", ">=", "San Francisco")
```

So I think you should just try:

```golang
iter := client.Collection("users").Where("customer_id", "<", 10000).Documents(ctx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually found that doc myself and tried what you suggested. It doesn't return anything. I think it's because customer_id is a string in Firestore. If I could cast it to an int it might work, but I haven't found out how to do that yet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this to happen is because you are having the filed set as "string" instead of "number". I had replicated the use case scenario and those are my findings:

My Firestore database:

```
collection: users
>> document: "auto_id"
   --customer_id: 111
>> document: "auto_id"
   --customer_id: 123
>> document: "auto_id"
   --customer_id: 4500
>> document: "auto_id"
   --customer_id: 3500
```

I have setup in Firestore each `customer_id` as string. Then when using method `Where("customer_id", "==", "111")` will give me `map[customer_id:111]` but when using `Where("customer_id", "<", "1000")` or `Where("customer_id", "<", 1000)` will give me nothing as you described.

Then I went to Firestore and changed the type of each filed from `string` to `number` and executed the code again, so I got:

```
 map[customer_id:111]
 map[customer_id:123]
```

My [full code example in GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Firestore/GO/load_users_with_id_less_than_1000.go) that worked for me.